# How to open a specific message entry in Android by id？

Tags: android

Like this, I know how to get the id from a message, but I don't konw how to open this message in default android app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("？？？？？？？？"+String.valueOf(mShowMessages.get(i).getId())));
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

The more important thing is, that I don't know how to search this question in Google developer docs, all things about Uri format that in the docs is...emmm I just don't know where they are.

Comment: which id does this represents and what exactly intent you require?

Comment: Actually I learnt that setComponent() works, but I don't know what to put in it(which refers to System Message Application)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations"+String.valueOf(mShowMessages.get(i).getId())));
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```